# figuring out the sum of angles from the addition of geometrical shapes within a circle

Tags: analytic-geometry

if you add a number with another you get the sum of the two.(1+1=2, 2+2=4) right?
but if you take a circle and put a horizontal line through it you have 4 angles in it. put another circle with a vertical line through it together with the other you should have a total of 8 angles. you actually have a total of twelve angles within your new circle. and if you do this with a triangle you end up with a total of 42 angles. why is this and is there an equasion to figure it out?

Comment: When I run a line through a circle, I see 8 angles, not 4.

Comment: contain the line within the circle

Comment: Well, then, if you have two circles, and one line segment contained in each, then you only have 8 angles, not 12.

Comment: yeah now put them together... if you read the title it clearly states ....WITHIN A CIRCLE

Comment: What do you mean, "put them together"? If I put the new circle inside the old one, the number of angles will depend on where I put it. Does it touch the horizontal line? Does it cross that line? You may find that instead of SHOUTING at the only person to display the least bit of interest in your question you'd be better off giving some thought to its exposition, and to editing it in such a way that someone other than yourself can understand what you are asking.

Comment: it is a very simple question if you put this / inside one circle and this \ inside the other then put them together you will end up with X inside a circle if you do it with triangles flip one triangle  180 degrees to end up with a hexagram. i dont think the degree in which you turn it has any bearing on the outcome because if you turn it 182 degrees you still have the same basic design and amount of intersections between lines but maybe im wrong

Comment: "then put them together" - what does that mean? I can think of a lot of ways to put two circles together. Do they intersect? Is one completely inside the other? Please, please, please take my comments seriously, and address them, and rewrite your question so it makes sense.